# Writing a CSV on Windows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I wrote this script that works fine on my Mac, but not so well on my Windows machine (where it needs to run).  I'm trying to append to a CSV.  Snippet:

```
with open('timeclock.csv', 'a') as timeclocklog:
    timeclockwriter = csv.writer(timeclocklog)
    timeclockwriter.writerow([now, inorout])
```

When I try that, I get no lines appended to my CSV.  If I change the `a` to `ab`, I'm told that "str does not support the buffer interface".  Okay, so I guess I need to convert my string to bytes somehow, but I can't seem to get there.  It doesn't need to allow for any weird characters -- the only input allowed are the words "in" or "out".

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Update:

Here's the CSV structure:

```
TIMESTAMP,IN-OUT
Tue Apr 15 10:23:05 2014,in
```

And the only input the script allows is either "in" or "out":

```
if (inorout.lower() == 'in') or (inorout.lower() == 'out'):
    # Do the stuff
```

Jeremy

Comment: are you using python 3.x+ by any chance?

Comment: I am in fact using 3.x.  I can't remember which .x offhand (I'm in a meeting).

Comment: I checked.  3.2.2 is running on this machine.

Comment: can you post a sample from the csv and a sample of what you would write to it please?

Comment: I'm tempted to just write a text file, but I don't want to abandon the question.

Comment: Did you try using default settings for windows CSV? e.i csv.writer(timeclocklog, quotechar='"', delimeter=','); that and set the file mode to 'wb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
import csv
now = 'Tue Apr 15 10:23:05 2014'
inorout = 'out'

with open('timeclock.csv', 'a', newline='') as timeclocklog:
    timeclockwriter = csv.writer(timeclocklog)
    timeclockwriter.writerow([now, inorout])
```

Comment: I don't get any errors when I do that, but I also don't get any new lines in my CSV.

Comment: That's it, @heinst!  I wasn't getting any new lines because Python couldn't find the CSV file until I told it the whole path.  Whew!  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Ah makes sense. The csv file I was using was in the same directory as the script. No problem!

Comment: Mine was in the same directory as well.  That's why I was confused.  At any rate, I also added this line so that I don't have to go figuring out the path when I put this into real use tomorrow: `timeclocklogfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'timeclock.csv')`.